# How to render QuillJS rich-text output to HTML

Tags: javascript, quill

I am a little stuck, I am working with Quill JS editor and have now got to the point where I need to render the output from the editor in a html document and possibly a PDF document (HTML is a priority)

How would I render output like this:

```
{
  "ops": [
    {"attributes":{"bold":true},"insert":"Test Post"},
    {"insert":"\n\nThis is a test post.\n"}
  ]
}
```

I have had a look around but cant seem to find out how to do this. I hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

```
editor.root.innerHTML
```

You will need to style it.

From there you can export to PDF with something like jsPDF or similar or bounce it to the server.

Example:

[Getting Quill content](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/amwpqk)

Comment: if I use `.innerHTML`  I will not be able to edit further.

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth: Not sure what your problem is, maybe open a new question ?

Comment: this is not how you use quilljs. So many ppl do this. Just delta!

Answer (score 4):

Quill delta itself designed to represent contents, not visualization.
as [documentation](https://quilljs.com/guides/designing-the-delta-format/) say, delta doesn't assign any meaning to attribute, `bold` can be `<strong>` or `<b>` or `<custom tag>` in html, it mean you can design your delta to represent your own content.

To render delta in your own format, you can use [quill-render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-render). so you can have 1 or more different format for render to your html and pdf.

Answer (score 3):

Quill doesn't output to HTML natively. But there are plugins that can render data from Quill, such as [quilljs-renderer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quilljs-renderer)